# Generic Model Based CRUD API Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there a built in or library based way to implement generic Eloquent/Model based views in Laravel for simple CRUD endpoints?

At the moment I am writing the logic for `index, store, destroy, update` manually, but all the code is essentially the same.

e.g.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
  $customer= CustomerInfo::find($id);
  $customer->delete();
}
```

I'm more used to Django and the DRF which implements a `ModelViewSet` class which handles all (most) of the logic for simple CRUD applications.

Comment: Have you tried Laravel resources which make all the methods needed for an endpoint. Please refer the link - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

> Implement generic Eloquent/Model based views in Laravel for simple CRUD endpoints

I'm not sure about that but Laravel provides route to model binding, which shortens your code. There's also `resource controller` which is already pretty much declare all needed methods for you. What's left is quite minimal. So after using `model binding` and resource controller, your `destroy()` method may look like:

```
public function destroy(CustomerInfo $customerInfo)
{
  $customerInfo->delete();
}
```

But the method name and its agrument is already declared like a placeholder, you just write `delete()` line. More about [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) and [resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Use single artisan command to have CRUD endpoints all in one.

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
```

Because of this common use case, Laravel resource routing assigns the typical create, read, update, and delete ("CRUD") routes to a controller with a single line of code. To get started, we can use the make:controller Artisan command's --resource option to quickly create a controller to handle these actions: